# Выполнение нескольких sql запросов через addBatch

Tags: java, jdbc

При использовании данного кода выполняется только самый первый запрос, в чем может быть причина?

```
String sql = "UPDATE students set имя ='" +
                        name.getText() + "'" +
                        "where имя = '" + reserveName + "' and класс = '" + reserveClass + "'";
                String sql1 = "UPDATE students set пол ='"
                         + sex.getText() +
                         "'where имя = '" + reserveName + "' and класс = '" + reserveClass + "'";
                Action.statement.addBatch(sql);
                Action.statement.addBatch(sql1);
                Action.statement.executeBatch();
                Action.statement.clearBatch();
```

Comment: Наверно потому, что в addBatch добавляются только идентичные запросы. А у вас структура данных отличается.

Comment: А какой метод следует использовать вместо него?

Comment: Достаточно одного запроса: `UPDATE students set имя = ... , пол = ... where ...`.

Comment: Запросы не могут меняться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Объединил всё в 1 запрос и всё прошло

```
String sql = "UPDATE students set имя ='" + name.getText() +
                                    "', пол = '" + comboSex.getSelectedItem() + "' " +
                                    ", класс = '" + clas.getText() + "' " +
                                    ", `день рождения` = '" + birth.getText() + "' " +
                                    ", `группа здоровья` = '" + comboHealth.getSelectedItem() + "' " +
                                    ", `физ группа` = '" + comboSport.getSelectedItem() + "' " +
                                    ", парта = '" + parta.getText() + "' " +
                                    ", `рекомендации врача` = '" + doc.getText() + "' " +
                                    ", `приоритет имени` = '" + namePriority + "' " +
                                    ", `приоритет класса` = '" + klasPriority + "' " +
                                    "where имя = '" + reserveName + "' and класс = '" + reserveClass + "'";
                            Action.statement.addBatch(sql);
                            Action.statement.executeBatch();
                            Action.statement.clearBatch();
                            MainJava.jTabPeople.removeAll();
                            Action.fill("select * from students  order by `Приоритет класса` desc, `Приоритет имени` asc");
```

Comment: Извините, а можно поподробней?